# make windows console cursor invisible with python ctypes modules

Tags: python, winapi, python-2.7, ctypes, windows-console

I've recently tried using the Console module for python 2.7 on Windows XP, but found that it was poorly documented and would crash on my machine.

So, what I'm doing now is essentially writing my own module, but have come across this bump where I can't figure out how to set the console cursor to be invisible using ctypes.windll.kernel32

How would I go about doing this? (using standard modules with python 2.7 (hopefully just ctypes))

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, probably.

```
from ctypes import *
class CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('dwSize', c_int),
                ('bVisible', c_int)]

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11

hStdOut = windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
cursorInfo = CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO()
cursorInfo.dwSize = 1
cursorInfo.bVisible = 0
windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorInfo(hStdOut, byref(cursorInfo))
```

Disclaimer: Untested.